# Bytes to image from Parse.com

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I'm trying to convert a Parse.com object into an image with Javascript. The object is of the type Bytes, and I can't convert it in any way. Can someone give me an example of how to turn it into a functional URL? I try to access it but it just keeps crashing.

Edit:

```
getURL: function () {
    var query = new Parse.Query("Token");
    query.limit(20);
    query.find().then(this.handleCallback.bind(this));
},
handleCallback: function (objects) {
    for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
        this.tokenSearch[i] = {
            imgURL: "data:image/png;base64," + objects[i].get("pic")
        };
    }
}
```

I have tried objects[i].get("pic").url(), objects[i].get("pic").toString('base64') and some other stuff, but it won't work!

Comment: Which ways have you tried? Please show us your trials and errors, perhaps you were close and just have a small mistake. You should edit your question to include the code.

Comment: What's your Parse class structure? Are you storing the image as a `PFFile`, or are you actually storing a byte array?

Comment: The attribute/column says "Bytes"!

Comment: @MarkusOlsson Is that the name of the column? Because I can't find a way to add a column with a "Bytes" data type. Is the actual data type of the column `Array`?

Comment: @mbm29414 No it is the type. It is not possible to add it but it is uploaded from an iOS device. According to the Parse.com documentation it should be a byte array. (Some information [here](https://parse.com/docs/data))

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store images and later have a URL you can load, you should switch to the `File` data type instead of pushing just a byte array. The documentation you linked recommends the following:

> There are two ways to store binary data. The Bytes type allows you to associate NSData/bytes[] types directly on a PFObject. This is recommended only for small pieces of binary-encoded data. For actual files (images, documents, etc.), the File type can be used by instantiating a PFFile/ParseFile and setting it on a field.

You have stored the actual byte array into the `pic` column of your Parse class. Therefore, that's all you get. If you chose instead to store it as a `File` (`PFFile` in iOS/OSX, `ParseFile` in Android), you could do what you're trying to do. As it is, Parse is merely storing the bytes as it would store any other data, such as a Date or a String. There's no URL data associated with it.

Here's how you can create and upload a `PFFile` from an iOS device:

```
- (void)updateloadImage:(UIImage *)image {
    PFFile *file = [PFFile fileWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)];
    PFObject *newToken = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Token"];
    newToken[@"pic"]   = file;
    [newToken saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
            // Do real error handling here
            // Now, you have :
            // 1. The "pic" saved to Parse as a PFFile
            // 2. The "token" saved to Parse as a PFObject
            // 3. The "pic" stored as a property on the "token"

    }
     ];
}
```

Once you have it stored that way on Parse, you would access it in the JavaScript SDK something like this:

```
function getURL() {
    var query = new Parse.Query("Token");
    query.limit(20);
    query.find().then(function (objects) {
        for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; i = i + 1) {
            this.tokenSearch[i] = {imgURL: objects[i].get("pic").url()};
        }
    });
}
```